# how can i make my search result in my website appear orderly

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM listing 
WHERE (MATCH(dir_heading) 
AGAINST ('$wtfld' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND busns_suburb LIKE '%".$whrfld."%' " ;
```

I want to add `ORDER BY` to this code but I can't implement it correctly.

Comment: Please share your table schema and data.

Comment: my table column is S/N, dir_heading, busns_name, busns_loc, busns suburb. and i want the search result to display in ORDER BY busns_name

Comment: Add the order by after your WHERE clause: ```ORDER BY busns_name```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, add the order by following the where clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM listing 
WHERE (MATCH(dir_heading) 
AGAINST ('$wtfld' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND busns_suburb LIKE '%".$whrfld."%' 
ORDER BY busns_name;" ;
```